# Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 43148176 bytes)

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to show categories & subcategories in a tree by using php&pdo
This is my code for it

```
if(! function_exists('fetchCategoryTree')){
    function fetchCategoryTree($status = 1, $spacing = '', $user_tree_array = '') {
        global $con;
        if (!is_array($user_tree_array)) {
            $user_tree_array = array();
        }
    
        $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * 
                                FROM `categories` 
                                WHERE `status` = ? 
                                ORDER BY `id` ASC");
        $stmt->execute(array($status));
        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
        if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
            foreach ($rows as $row) {

                $user_tree_array[] = array("id" => $row['id'], 
                                            "name" => $spacing . $row['name']);
                $user_tree_array = fetchCategoryTree($row['id'], 
                                $spacing . '&nbsp;&nbsp;', $user_tree_array);
            }
        }
        return $user_tree_array;
    }
}
```

I had tried all the regular solutions like to increase the memory limit to 2048 MB and added this line before the line error code

```
ini_set('memory_limit','-1');
```

but it is still the same error show

Comment: setting `memory_limit` to -1 is just hiding a problem and will not solve anything. Also if you want to set memory limit to -1. you don't need to do it in a loop. Try chunking the results or put an offset / limit in your query. Out of curiosity, how many categories, sub categories are we talking about?

Comment: Ok, lets start by seeing the Actual Error Message please, in the question and not the title

Comment: its only 12 categories

Comment: 33554432 means you have an initial memory limit of 32M, thats a bit small for most sites. In which file did you change the `memory_limit` parameter

Comment: in php.ini file

Comment: I haven't analysed the code, but you're probably entering an infinite loop. Running identical queries in a loop almost always harms performance for no good reason. Instead, grab the information at once, in a single SQL query.

Comment: ___in php.ini file___ But there are often more than one of these. Sometimes there is one for Apache and another for the CLI. So did you check with `phpinfo()` that you were editing the correct `php.ini`

Comment: @BlockchainOffice Sorry about your downvotes, but your attempt at an answer was nothing to do with the actual problem

Comment: @RiggsFolly,really? set apache or php script limit? what is the ini_set for?

Comment: Yes, thats just clearing up one of the OP's attempts at getting away with the code they wrote

Comment: _,really? set apache or php script limit? what is the ini_set for?_ @BlockchainOffice Its a comment not an answer

Comment: It looks like you are query with one condition `WHERE status = ?` and use with `fetchCategoryTree($row['id']...`. This doesn't look like it can be matched between `id` and `status`. If you would like to make function call for sub categories, please check about this again because it is not between parent id and child id.

Comment: For example: You have first query `where status = 1` and if this result contain id1 and if id1 has status = 1. This means you will get indefinitely loop. And this infinite loop can cause memory exhausted or execution timeout. I have shared some class about nested set on [GitHub](https://github.com/Rundiz/nested-set) that maybe not help with your code directly but you can use some of them or all (depend on you).